# Difference between LASSO penalty in neural network and just LASSO regression

Tags: neural-network, multiclass-classification, dimensionality-reduction, regularization

I wonder whether those two have any significant differences.

I think in neural network, the lasso penalty put on the loss function makes the model simpler and introduces more sparsity by automatically reducing some of the features to 0. I assume that's basically the lasso regression is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its „pure“ form, Lasso is just a penalty on top of the RSS of a normal (OLS) regression. The result is that your OLS **parameters** are shrunken.

[image]

See section 6.2.2 of „[Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf#page229)“.

In neural nets the **weights** are shrunken (there can be many of them and usually much more than in normal regression). In Keras/TF this happens [layer-wise](http://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.2/regularizers/). See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136150/224077) post for some background.

So the concepts are quite different. Also the objective of using L1 can be quite different, e.g. when it is used to approach high dimensional problems in OLS. What they have in common is that you try to get rid of unnecessary „noise“ in your estimation to get a better fit (and to avoid overfitting).

Note that **NOT** the features are shrunken but parameters/weights are shrunken.

Answer (score 0):

I think Lasso Regression, is a type of regression model which implements the lasso penalty (L1 regularization) within its algorithm (different from normal regression algorithms).

Lasso penalty is more of a generalized penalty that can be put on any learning algorithm.

The concept behind both ideas are the same, but their area of implementation is different.

Hope this helps !!